# DropBox login not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, dropbox

Using the DropBox api I attempt to log on with any details using their popup login form -

```
DBLoginController *dropBoxLoginController = [[DBLoginController new] autorelease];
dropBoxLoginController.delegate = self;
[dropBoxLoginController presentFromController:self];
```

and it will always trigger the exception warnings which DropBox have thoughtfully provided throughout their code, specifically in the method -

```
-(id)initWithText:andSecret:forRequest:usingMethod:
```

This fails to log in, & nothing I can do will make it work. Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Silly me... (not unusual)

I didn't twig that the app had to sign in first, before any user can, using the following -

```
DBSession *dbSession = 
[[[DBSession alloc] initWithConsumerKey:@"My Consumer Key"
  consumerSecret:@"My Consumer Secret"]
 autorelease];
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
```

After that, the user login works fine...